# how to include js file using script tag in jquery codes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, include

I want to include js file in jQuery scripts, when data is fetched from database using `$.ajax` and do something without refreshing the page

for example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "content.php",
  data: {vals: "value"},
  success : function(response) { 
    $(body).append(response)
    showScrollStyle();
  }
}); 

function showScrollStyle() {
 // here should include 3 js file for change scroll style
}
```

response will show a div with `500px height` and width that have `overflow:auto;` style and if text of div will be more than of `500px;` vertical scroll will be show automatially, I have 3 js file that I should include there for change scroll styles and type.

I tried `$.getScrpit()` function but it will refresh the page and will show just a white page.

how can I do this? thank you

EDIT 1:

I created some codes that i think can explain what i want

HTML CODE

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    textScroll()
   function textScroll() {

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "content.php",
          data: {val: "text_div"},
          success : function(response) { 
            $("body").append(response);
            showScrollStyle()
          }
        }); 
    }

    });

    function showScrollStyle() {
        // jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js should import in here for work with new elemnts
    }
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/scroll_style.css">

<style>
body {

    background-color:#369;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>


</body>
</html>
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php 

    include 'Connections.php';  // connect to database

    $val =  $_POST['val'];
    $query = "SELECT contains FROM textarea WHERE name='".$val."' LIMIT 1";
            //  echo $query;
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['contains'];  
        }
    }   
    else
    {
        echo $mysqli->error;
    }

?>
```

SOMETHING STORED IN textarea TABLE

```
<div style=" display:inline-block; margin:auto; width:800px; height:400px; overflow:auto;" id="rulesScroll" class="font c_blue_dark mCustomScrollbar interfo_section">
  <span style=" display:inline-block; margin:30px; font-size:44px;" id="newsContain">
               text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
  </span> 
</div>
```

Note: if you need to jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js you can download scroll bar plugIn in here http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.
Are you just trying to include a javascript library on your page that you want to use? Cause then you can use the <script src="<file path.js>"></script>

Comment: when some element created in <body></body> tag so you can include scprit file as you said (<scrpit src="file path.js"></scrpit>) but when i include some elemnt in body tag with $.ajax it don't work with icluded scrpit form <head></head> tag they are new elements and need new scrpit for change them, Thanks

Comment: Still unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I think he is trying to include the script dynamically when it is required rather than loading initially.

Comment: yes, i will do that, for example after get response from $.ajax i want include some functions when mouse is over the div change backgound color and many other actions. i saved this functions in other files and i want iclude that files ind work true with the elemnts

Answer (score 0):

I have used $.getScript function and it is working fine for me. Have you used function in right way? Please check below code.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.getScript demo</title>
  <style>
  .block {
     background-color: blue;
     width: 150px;
     height: 70px;
     margin: 10px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body">
 <button onclick="load()" id="load">&raquo; Load</button>
<button id="go">&raquo; Run</button>
<div class="block"></div>

<script>
function load()
{
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/search",
      data: {vals: "value"},
      success : function(response) {
      $("#body").append(response);
        showScrollStyle();
      }
    }); 
}

function showScrollStyle() {
 // here should include 3 js file for change scroll style
 var url = "https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color.js";
$.getScript( url, function() 
{
  $( "#go" ).click(function() {
    $( ".block" )
      .animate({
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 180, 180)"
      }, 1000 )
      .delay( 500 )
      .animate({
        backgroundColor: "olive"
      }, 1000 )
      .delay( 500 )
      .animate({
        backgroundColor: "#00f"
      }, 1000 );
  });
});
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code is not refreshing the page.

Comment: thank you @Bhaskar Rajoriya the elemnts that your wrote in your code is in <body></body> tag but my elemnts is new elemnt that will insert from database with $.ajax and can't work with all scrpit included in php file wity <script></script> tag or $.getScript function

Comment: please include your elemnts with $.ajax in your page and import your js file after get response.i think you will see $.getScript don't work too

Comment: I am unable to understand that what you want. Please more explain or use jsfiddle or anything to share you code. I will make it right.
Thanks

Comment: I think I can't create my codes in jsfiddle because it need database for insert my elemnt , i think for other way

Comment: I added my code sample in question, please review that, thank you

Comment: You are doing wrong. if you want to get data using ajax then you have to use return in the place of echo. First you must use best practices to use php with ajax.
I am unable to find problem with provided contents.
Thanks :)

Comment: problem is scroll style is defult style when i get response from database , but i want change it with jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js file, this js file doing work when the elemnts is in html <body> tag but don't work with $.ajax response

Comment: so i think i must add elemnts in HTML <body> tag and there is not any other ways?